# Find a list owner/point of contact (SharePoint Online, no admin access)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, groups, office-365-groups

My office is changing over to MS 365/SharePoint Online and we're looking for a general method to identify the owner of a given list or library, with standard Reader-level access. Users can get to the list's Permissions dialog, but unfortunately our IS team has everything set up with groups rather than individual names... and users can't display the membership of groups, just "Group Name."

What we need is a quick and simple way to start from a link and determine, "Okay, this is some kind of SharePoint list. Now, who owns this thing, so I can ask them what it's for and how it's used?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to find the name of user who created a list/library from SharePoint UI (in browser).

You can check who created a list/library in SharePoint using PowerShell script and/or SharePoint REST API.

Check:

1. [Find Who has Created a List or Library using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/find-who-created-list-library-in-sharepoint-powershell.html)
2. [How can I check who created a list or library in SharePoint Online?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f91b7d04-c254-4bf3-b63d-6a7758890c11/how-can-i-check-who-created-a-list-or-library-in-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)